# Stutter every few seconds. How to fix this?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, performance, physics, box2d

I've been following this tutorial closely.

http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/

After some set of problems, I got it to work on my T-mobile G1.

Now I have 4-5 objects(balls) drawn on the screen. I have the balls spawn around the middle of the screen and start to fall.

Problem: The game stutter every few seconds. I examined the Logcat and believe that the GC is the culprit.

However, I've seen many games using box2D and produce smooth gameplay(Forexample, Andengine demo).

How did they do that? How did they stop the GC from kicking in?(assuming the GC is really the culprit)

Any opinions are welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, if your examining the Logcat, then your running this on the emulator, right?

Don't trust the emulator in this case.  As I understand, the way it reads/writes to memory make it a bad baseline for judging how your application will run on an actual phone.

If it works on your G1, then more than likely it will work on other phones too.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying. But I didn't use the emulator. I use the G1 attached with USB cable. This way you can see the Logcat coming from the G1.

Comment: So, what happens when you run it without your PC attached?

Answer (score 0):

Stock JBox2D uses tons of object creation in its calculations. There are people working on an [Android NDK Box2D](https://github.com/dschaefer/android-box2d), but that's a bit more work to get going than just using a Java library. I don't believe there's any (yet) version of JBox2D that has solved the GC churn issue that you seem to be having. I'm attempting one, but I don't know how much benefit it will provide or how close it'd get to the NDK version.

You may want to look into [APE Physics for Android](http://code.google.com/p/ape-physics-for-android/). It supports substantially fewer aspects of physics simulation, but that may be alright for some applications.